# Create button in Excel to copy the file?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I want to create a button in Excel 2010 that when clicked, it will save the currently opened Excel file and copy it to C:\temp.

Is this possible? Perhaps a macro should trigger an exe program, or can be all done within the macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
With ActiveWorkbook
  .Save
  .SaveCopyAs "C:\Temp\Copy.xls"
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

In your button's `Click` event, you can copy the current worksheets into another workbook and then save that in C:\Temp... Something like:

```
Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Another Sheet")).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Temp\Copy.xls"
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: There are dozens of sheets and more are added. Plus there are macros I want perserved. Is there a way to copy the whole file (eval shell commands)?

Comment: There's `FileCopy`, which will just copy any file (supplying source and destination parameters). You can use this to copy anything, but the problem you'll have is that, as the workbook will be trying to copy itself, it will error because itself is obviously still open and locked.